# Read and return Json Array to Index View

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I'm having challenges with reading deserialized json array and returning it to view. I am able to deserialize json, but then can't proceed to return the values and send it to view.

I get the error, 'The name user does not exist in the current context'. Any idea why this is happening?. Please see my code below

Controller

```
     public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //Method 
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserCall()
    {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                //Httpclient code goes here, removed for brevity
                
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var respstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    UserVM user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<userVM>(respstring); //the code work up to this point
                }
               
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserManage", user);//Error 'The name user does not exist in the current context'

            }
        }
```

Model

```
    public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
    public string register { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string deregister { get; set; }
}

public class user
{
    public IEnumerable<User> user { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the Json string

```
  {
  "user": [   
  {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Name1",
  "surname": "Surname1",
  "register": "2020-05-07",
  "status": "A",
  "deregister": "2021-05-06"
},
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": Name2
  "surname": "Surname2",
  "register": "2020-08-07",
  "status": "L"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move user variable definition outside of the if block so you can access it.

```
//Method 
public async Task<IActionResult> UserCall()
{
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Httpclient code goes here, removed for brevity
            UserVM user = null; // <---- here
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var respstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<userVM>(respstring); //the code work up to this point
            }
           
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserManage", user); //Error 'The name user does not exist in the current context'

        }
    }
```